# How to access ContentView objects (x:Name) when included in a ListView Header?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms (3.4)
How can I access in the code behind, a ContentView object (x:Name) when this ContentView is in a ListView Header Template.
It seems that I cannot access it with the x:Name. In the following example, I cannot access the ContentView in my code behind by reference it as "myView".

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <views:SampleView x:Name="myView" />
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
```

Also the `var myView = this.FindByName<ContentView>("myView");` returns `null`.
Thanks

Comment: you can't access elements in templates by name

Comment: Is there another way to reference elements in the header template or is it impossible? Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Instead of using headertemplate you can use `ListView.Header` and wrap this content view. Its accessible from code behind BTW

Comment: That is not possible for me. I bind the header with `<ListView Header="{Binding Header}"` so I cannot use the header tag twice to add elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HeaderTemplate` use `Header` to fill in custom content view,

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Header>
        <views:SampleView x:Name="myView" />
</ListView.Header>
```

**Code behind**

```
var header = listViewName.Header;
//it will be sampleview which was set.
```

Use `header` to get access of individual elements of that `ContentView`